# Does Thymeleaf can manipulate model like AngularJS?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

So, quesiton is in the topic. Ok, with Thymeleaf I can get model attributes(`${attr1}`) and render page with it. But what if I need manipulate my model, which after render is exists only on my page? I want to add/edit/remove data of my model. In AngularJS I can do it pretty easy: in js-file I have variables, which have biderectional data-binding with html-page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three components in manipulating with template in java

1. Template file
2. Java object
3. Template engine

Template engine is responsible for combining the java object with template file and generate pure html file all this process occurs at server and the response that client which receives contains html no custom javascript libraries like angular
-js do handle this data binding at client.